# Given a subcollection of a powerset, do these "separation" relations have names?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $X$ denote a set and $\mathcal{F}$ denote a subcollection of $\mathcal{P}(X).$ Do the following relations on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ have a name?

For $A,B \subseteq X$, call $A$ *partially* separated from $B$ iff we can find $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A \subseteq F$ and $B \subseteq F^c$. Call $A$ and $B$ *totally* separated iff each is partially separated from the other. Call $A$ and $B$ *strongly* separated by $\mathcal{F}$ if we can find **disjoint** $F,G \in \mathcal{F}$ with $A \subseteq F$ and $B \subseteq G.$

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like lattice theory. They have similar notions of separation that does not involve topology. Check out this paper, bottom of the second page: http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume14_2/395496.pdf. If I find out more I'll edit this answer.